# Call unity from android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have a unity project which uses an android libarary. From my android library I calls

```
UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("GameObject", "recieve", "Test Message");
```

Where my C# script attached to GameObject has the method

```
public void receive(string message){
        str = "received" + message;
        //do something
    }
```

But it seems when android calls UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage() C# receive() method does not get called. Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "android library"?

Comment: You mean you have written some java classes for android, export them to jar file, convert jar to dll, then import dll into your unity project. Is that what you mean?

Comment: no I am adding the jar file to assests/plugins/android

Comment: In your jar you have a class that uses UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage method ??

Comment: Can you provide us with that class??

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have a typo on your method name (recieve):

```
UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("GameObject", "recieve", "Test Message");
```

instead of:

```
UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("GameObject", "receive", "Test Message");
```